# WiFi issue, on xubuntu

Tags: wireless, xubuntu

I am only able to connect to WiFi for a brief period of time at best, seemingly less than 180 seconds, and then the internet won't work at all for tens of minutes. With Ethernet, it seems that my computer doesn't even recognize the wired connection.

The issue doesn't seem to be the router, because every other device in the house is connected and working fine. It also doesn't appear to be computer hardware, because I am currently operating on the same computer from a live USB (of the same xubuntu install, in fact).

I am curious as to something I may have toggled that could cause this problem? I really can't think of anything. My hope is to avoid doing another install of the OS, because that would be tiresome.

Thanks for any help! keep in mind I am a total noob when it comes to command line.

EDIT: I did a network diagnostic, it's here: http://pastebin.com/raw/WAk5BvVi - thanks for the suggestion! Ethernet seems to be working now too, because of magic or something.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. Also, please open a separate question for either the Ethernet or the WiFi issue (and include the same diagnostics output) because they're unrelated.